# Outgoing HTTPS proxy using apache

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration, ssl, proxy

I have an HTTP/HTTPS web server running on Apache 2.2.22, and I would like this machine to act as a proxy server as well. So far I have tried to modify the `proxy.conf` file as follows:

```
ProxyRequests on
<Proxy *>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /var/www/proxy/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Proxy>
ProxyVia On
```

Apache accepted this configuration, but accessing any website via this proxy results in the following message in Firefox/Palemoon:

> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.

I suspect this is related to the fact that I didn't specify a port on which the proxy server should listen (I tried to connect to the regular HTTP/HTTPS ports). Is it possible to run a web-server and a proxy on the same port? Are there any other obvious reasons why my configuration isn't working?